# OS X scan folder for new html files

Tags: macos, automation, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for a way to scan a selected folder for new html files.

The idea is to save html files on my mobile then have those files sync to my home system and then download (through a download manager) while I travel.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the terminal for such kind of jobs.
For listing all html files in a folder you can issue the command:

```
find . -name "*.html"
```

For listing all the html files that were created in the past n days you can use the following line (with minor modifications)

```
find . -name "*.html" -ctime -n
```

where n = 1 if you are searching for files created today, 2 if you are searching for files of the previous day etc.

Comment: `-ctime` is inode change time. `-Btime` would be creation time.